# Elasticsearch in an existing JHipster project

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, jhipster

I'm creating a JHipster application and identified now the necessity of a [full text search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). Iknow JHipster is integrated with Elasticseach but I didn't enabled it when I've created the project. Is there a easy (or painless) way to integrate Elasticsearch in an existing JHipster project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can edit your project's `.yo-rc.json` file and add a line `"searchEngine": "elasticsearch",`, re-run `yo jhipster` and merge manually the changes. You may have to re-generate entities too as explained in [our doc](http://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/): "Generating an entity a second time"

Comment: Sorry :). What I mean is I have done this. But it does not modify the application-dev.yml. Nor did it changes the HTML view. Even after modifying the application-dev.yml embedded elasticsearch does not start. Glad you saw this message. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Well, if you added `"searchEngine": "elasticsearch",` line to your `yo-rc.json`, I cannot see why it would not work. I clarified the instructions in answer.

Comment: ok. my bad .. I added "searchEngine": "true". I will recheck this and update